# UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter printing extra blank page

Tags: ios, printing

When using UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter to print a few lines of simple HTML, it puts out a blank page first, then the page with the text.  The code is as follows, and very simple:

```
- (void) printSomething;
{
    if (![UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
        return;

    NSString* markupText =@"<html><body>THIS IS A TEST</body></html>";

    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter* printFormatter =[ [ [UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:markupText] autorelease];

    UIPrintInteractionController* printInteractionController =[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printInteractionController.printFormatter =printFormatter;
    printInteractionController.delegate =self;  
    //printInteractionController.showsPageRange =YES;       

    [printInteractionController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];                                 
}
```

Now, if I uncomment the *showsPageRange =YES*, a single page prints as expected, BUT the UIPrintInteractionController takes several seconds to appear.  Enough to make the user wonder if the app froze.

The very first line of the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter docs state "*Instances of the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter class lay out HTML markup text for a multipage print job*".  It'd be kinda crazy if the formatter prints multiple pages, regardless of content...

Any idea what's wrong here?  Other apps do this without any issues.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by having the correct HTML skeleton:

```
NSString *htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Title</title></head><body>Hello!</body></html>"
```

Comment: And also, make sure `<style></style>` is after `<!DOCTYPE html>`: `<!DOCTYPE html><style></style><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Title</title></head><body>Hello!</body></html>`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with appearance of second blank page with `printInteractionController.showsPageRange = NO;` and found the Apple example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/drawingprintingios.pdf) (page 67). Here is it:

```
- (IBAction)printContent:(id)sender {
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController
                                         sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = self.documentName;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *htmlFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:self.htmlString];
    htmlFormatter.startPage = 0;
    htmlFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
    pic.printFormatter = htmlFormatter;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError
      *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
        } };
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES
                    completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

This example uses `printInteractionController.showsPageRange = YES;`, and works fine, but if replace this line with

`printInteractionController.showsPageRange = NO;`, it prints extra second blank page.

So it seems that `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` is implicitly intended to be used with `printInteractionController.showsPageRange = YES;`, or it's just an API bug.

Comment: I already have `showsPageRange` set to `YES`. But it is still printing one extra blank page appended to the last.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and i found out it was being caused by the html code

```
style='page-break-after:always;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Hassy mentioned in his answer, the issue may be with the html/css code.

In my case, I was setting `html, body {min-height: 100%;}` which probably didn't go well with some margins/padding, but the issue can be anything related to css.
Setting a `background-color` to `body` will help check if this is indeed the issue (if the color overlaps on the 'blank' page, then the issue is with the styling).